# `nohup` does not work properly with `&&`

Tags: nohup

I want to make a delayed background execution, for delay I use `sleep [anyseconds] && [execution]` for background I use `nohup`

Simple example of `nohup` alone:

`nohup date &>> out.log &`

And of course you can find print out of the execution of `date` in `out.log`.

But I want to delay the execution, like 15 seconds, so a little combination:

`nohup sleep 15 && date &>> out.log &`

This time it does not work properly, `sleep 15` got executed while the `date` will not always do - If you shut down the terminal, it will not execute anything after the `&&`.

What is wrong with `nohup`? It surrenders to `&&`??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are in bash, where `nohup` is a command of the system (coreutils).

In bash the `&&` mark the end of a commandline. In your case the `nohup` gets from the shell only the parameters `sleep 15`. All the rest is the next command for the shell.

As `nohup` is not a shell, you can not use parenthesis to "extend" the parameters to `nohup`, because `nohup` can not interpret it and does not know what to do with it.

One solution would be to create a script (e.g. `sleepdate`) which contains `sleep 15 && date` and use this as parameter to `nohup`:

```
nohup ./sleepdate &>> out.log &
```

or use the bash (which can interpret `&&`) as parameter to `nohup`

```
nohup bash -c 'sleep 15 && date' &>> out.log &
```